# discovering computers on LAN

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

i use ubuntu 10.04, when i go to *places>network* ubuntu finds some (10-20) computers, sometimes nothing at all. my dorm LAN in fact is large (at least 1000 computers). why is it this way? does the network's firewall prohibits this?

Answer (score 1):

Just because it doesn't show up in Places > Network does not mean they don't exist. I remember when I compared that to the domain listing on a Windows computer right next to me and Nautilus's list was much shorter than the Windows list.

As @jrc03c said, it could be that your sub-netted differently. TMK Nautilus does not know of computers in 10.2.2.X if your in 10.2.3.X. You are going to have to consult the domain list.

I think though this is an answer to a workaround, not the actual question. You can talk to other computers regardless of the subnet directly if you know their IP or Net name. Simply goto Connect to Server > Windows Share and fill in your information

Comment: Quackstar - 10.2.2.X and 10.2.3.X are not necessarily different subnets

Answer (score 0):

While the dorm LAN might be large, your network admins might've divided you all up into subnets.  This might explain why you can't see others, even if they're physically nearby.  I don't know much about networking, but I think I've encountered this particular difficulty before for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is like this I have 5 computers on my network and when I use network neighborhood
I rarely see all my computers but if you know the computers name right click on the persons my computer icon and look at the name then only if they're sharing files you can go to your computer and click start,run and type 2 \\ (backslashes) then the computers name no spaces and you will see they're shared folders. you could even map to those drives if you want.